# Detect end of \input-file (not \read-file) in Knuthian TeX?

Tags: tex-core, conditionals, plain-tex

In Knuthian-TeX I'd like to have a macro which switches to verbatim-category-code-régime and then calls another macro which processes characters from the current input-file one by one until reaching the end of the current input-file.

Something like:

```
\def\initprocessloop
  {%
    \begingroup
    \catcode`\\=12 \catcode`\{=12 \catcode`\}=12 \catcode`\$=12 %
    \catcode`\&=12 \catcode`\#=12 \catcode`\^=12 \catcode`\^^M=12 %
    \catcode`\^^I=12 \catcode`\_=12 \catcode`\^^A=12 \catcode`\%=12 %
    \catcode`\~=12 \catcode`\ =12 \processloop
  }
\def\processloop #1%
  {%
    There is the character ``\string#1.''
    \if⟨end of current input-file is not reached⟩%
    \expandafter\processloop\else\expandafter\endgroup\fi
  }
```

Question:

Is it possible in Knuthian-TeX to implement a test `\if⟨end of current input-file is not reached⟩..\else..\fi`?

I *think* in eTeX I could use `\everyeof` for this, but I am explicitly asking for Knuthian-TeX.

I don't want to use `\read` because `\read` successively  reads brace-balanced sets of lines with as few lines as possible and whenever such a set is read a macro is defined which I don't really need and therefore see as waste of memory.

Comment: but with verbatim catcodes there are no balanced braces so read will read a line at a time

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I suppose Jim Beam has large input-files with many lines and doesn't want so many macro-assignments...

Comment: @UlrichDiez I used to worry about that sort of thing but then I ran a beamer document with `\tracingall` and gave up worrying.

Comment: @JimBeam Is the question "academical"? In use-cases nowadays -i'd stick to TeX-engines with eTeX-extensions and do s.th. with `\everyeof`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle :-)))))

Answer (score 6):

As the end of file is `\outer` (grrr) you can't get past it with a macro argument but you can consume it with `\let` so, with some undocumented restrictions you could report the file

```
abc
123
\hbox{123}
```

as

```
the letter a
the letter b
the letter c
the character ^^M
the character 1
the character 2
the character 3
the character ^^M
the character \
the letter h
the letter b
the letter o
the letter x
the character {
the character 1
the character 2
the character 3
the character }
the character ^^M
```

Using

```
\def\zz{\afterassignment\zzz\let\tmp= }
\def\zzz{\ifx\tmp\endgroup\endgroup\else\zzzz\expandafter\zz\fi}
\def\zzzz{\immediate\write20{\meaning\tmp}}

\def\setup#1{%
\begingroup
\catcode`\^^M=12 %
\catcode`\\=12 %
\catcode`\{=12 %
\catcode`\}=12 %
\catcode`\ =12 %
\catcode`\%=12 %
\expandafter\zz\input #1 %
\endgroup
}


\setup{\jobname.txt}



\bye
```

Comment: You may need to make more characters catcode 12, depending..

Answer (score 3):

You wish a **macro** to detect the end of an `\input`-file?

TeXbook, Chapter 20: Definitions (also called Macros), says:

> [...] When a macro definition is preceded by `\outer`, the corresponding control sequence will not be allowed to appear in any place where tokens are being absorbed at high speed. **An `\outer` macro cannot appear in an argument [...], nor can it appear in the parameter text or the replacement text of a definition, nor in the preamble to an alignment, nor in conditional text that is being skipped over.**
> If an `\outer` macro does show up in such places, TeX stops what it is doing and reports either a "runaway" situation or an "incomplete" conditional. **The end of an input file** or alignment template **is also considered to be `\outer` in this sense;** [...]

I doubt detecting the end of an input-file only by means of purely expandable routines (e.g., fully expandable macros or `\if..`-conditionals) is possible in Knuthian-TeX.

I suggest using an engine where you can take avantage of ε-TeX-extensions and where `\everyeof` can be used to drop in tokens which definitely are not verbatim-régime and therefore can be cranked out.

I think processing large input-files character-wise might take time.

---

---

From what is said in TeXbook, Chapter 20 one can deduce that - unlike TeX's mechanisms for grabbing macro arguments/parameter texts of definitions/replacement texts of definitions/preambles to alignments/conditional text that is to be skipped over - TeX's `\futurelet`-assignment-mechanism does not interfere with the fact of ends of files being `\outer`.

Thus one can (ab?)use `\futurelet` for getting ends of files out of the way before having macros grab arguments.

Of course this implies having a `\futurelet`-assignment with each argument-grabbing-iteration, so this is probably not what you want, but this trick is presented for the sake of completeness.

Sample file **sample.tex** to be processed verbatim via `\input`:

```
abc
123
\hbox{123}
```

The code for processing `\input`-file verbatim:

```latex
\long\def\firstoftwo#1#2{#1}%
\long\def\secondoftwo#1#2{#2}%
\def\initprocessloop#1%
  {%
    \begingroup
    \catcode`\\=12 \catcode`\{=12 \catcode`\}=12 \catcode`\$=12 %
    \catcode`\&=12 \catcode`\#=12 \catcode`\^=12 \catcode`\^^M=12 %
    \catcode`\^^I=12 \catcode`\_=12 \catcode`\^^A=12 \catcode`\%=12 %
    \catcode`\~=12 \catcode`\ =12 %
    \expandafter\futurelet\expandafter\scratchy\expandafter\processloop\input"#1"\relax
  }%
\begingroup
\endlinechar=-1 % <- ends of lines will not yield spaces with this setting.
\catcode`\^^M=12 \catcode`\^^I=12 \catcode`\^^A=12 %
\firstoftwo{
  \endgroup
  \def\processloop#1
    {
      \ifx\relax#1\expandafter\firstoftwo\else\expandafter\secondoftwo\fi
      {\endgroup}{
        \par There is the %
             \if\string#1^^Mreturn character\else
               \if\string#1^^Ihorizontal tab character\else
                 \if\string#1^^Astart of heading character\else
                   character ``{\tt\string#1}''
                 \fi
               \fi
             \fi
             .
        \futurelet\scratchy\processloop
      }
    }
}{}%
%%
\initprocessloop{sample.tex}
\bye
```

pdf-output:

[image]